# armcc to armclang porting error: unknown register name 'cp15:0:c9:c12:0'

Tags: arm, clang, armclang

I am trying to migrate my source code compilation from armcc compiler v5.06 to armclang v6. And I see armclang errors out saying it can not recognize cp15 registers. It looks like there might be a change in armcc vs clang as how to declare the registers. However, I could not find anything on the migration docs or in compiler doc.

**Here is the code snippet -**

```
void reset_clock_count(void)
{
    register uint32_t reg_cp15_pmcr __asm("cp15:0:c9:c12:0");
    reg_cp15_pmcr |=  RESET_CYCLE_COUNTER;
}
```

**And error snippet -**

```
error: unknown register name 'cp15:0:c9:c12:0' in asm
    register uint32_t reg_cp15_pmcr __asm("cp15:0:c9:c12:0");
                                          ^
```

I see same errors for other places for similarly declared register. Any pointer on what might have gone wrong will be helpful.

**Edit :**  the actual answer is the below.

```
register uint32_t val;
__asm volatile ("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0": "=r"(val));
val |= RESET_CYCLE_COUNTER;
__asm volatile ("mcr p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0":: "r"(val));
```

Comment: colons are not part of that syntax, did you try commas?

Comment: if you cut and paste from the arm documentation for the register access gnu is pretty good at supporting that (well last several versions)

Comment: you can use .inst or .word and the machine code for the instruction then disassemble that and cut and paste that syntax and there is a chance that will work (not always the case with gnu, but often)

Comment: ahh this is clang but it is using gnu as yes?  either way same answer that syntax is not normal at all for those accesses. you also need the mrc or mcr in front of it.

Comment: granted assembly language is specific to the tool not the target so perhaps you have the right syntax for the target but simply need the mrc/mcr

Comment: @old_timer
I tried -
reg_cp15_pmcr __asm("mcr cp15, 0, c9, c12, 0");
reg_cp15_pmcr __asm("mcr cp15:0:c9:c12:0");
No luck.
btw, forgot to add, this is for cortex A5 which is armv7

Comment: the mcr syntax is the same from armv4 on through armv7...

Comment: when you looked in the cortex a5 technical reference manual that is the syntax used for accessing that register?

Comment: To access the PMCR, read or write the CP15 registers with:
MRC p15, 0, <Rt>, c9, c12, 0; Read Performance Monitor Control Register
MCR p15, 0, <Rt>, c9, c12, 0; Write Performance Monitor Control Register

Answer (score 1):

Please read the manual first, and this was also mentioned in the comments too.

```
To access the PMCR, read or write the CP15 registers with: 
MRC p15, 0, <Rt>, c9, c12, 0; Read Performance Monitor Control Register 
MCR p15, 0, <Rt>, c9, c12, 0; Write Performance Monitor Control Register
```

cut and paste that into my code, select a register

```
MRC p15, 0, r0, c9, c12, 0
```

using gnu assembler:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   ee190f1c    mrc 15, 0, r0, cr9, cr12, {0}
```

using clang as an assembler

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   ee190f1c    mrc 15, 0, r0, cr9, cr12, {0}
```

No warnings nor errors.

Please read documentation first.

I cannot see how that syntax would work with any tool since the register was not specified.  But also remember that inline assembly is very specific to the compiler and not assumed to be portable in any way.  So if armcc supported that strange syntax no reason whatsoever to expect clang to.

Always use real assembly first and only after that maybe inline, but it is very rare for inline to be worth the effort.  You must disassemble it often to see that it is building the right instructions.

You have a lot more work for this inline asm to do anything useful anyway, you will have success faster with real assembly.

```
.globl read_pmcr
read_pmcr:
    MRC p15, 0, r0, c9, c12, 0
    bx lr
    
.globl write_pmcr   
write_pmcr:
    MCR p15, 0, r0, c9, c12, 0
    bx lr
```

And of course before starting any assembly you have to have the relevant documentation first.

Comment: Hi,
First of all I don't know who flagged this question as irrelevant
Secondly, the armcc way of calling is not strange. Please read doc - https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359125006491.htm
Also I did not expect it to be portable straightforward. I wanted a suggestion since I could not find any example.

Comment: anything assembly starts with the processor documentation which clearly shows examples of the instructions, really easy to find.  First thing one would try to do.  The linked page also shows similar clues.  so examples were easy to find.  stackoverflow is not here to read documents nor search the net for you.  the keil solution is extremely strange for that instruction and atypical for inline asm to be used in that way.

Comment: I had added the actual answer. Thanks for all the supposedly "hints"